# Flutter initState called every time I re-enter a page

Tags: flutter, state, navigation-drawer

I have three pages, A, B, C, and I navigate between them through a Drawer.

**My goal is to get initState to be called only once (when the page is inserted in the widget tree), so that the state of each page is not reinitialized when I return to it.**

My fist try was to use `Navigator.of(context).PushNamed(routeName)` as shown in the code below.
Probably this doesn't work because if from A I call B and then A again, the navigator stack is

[A] --> [B, A] --> [A, B, A] and not

[A] ->  [B, A] --> [A]

so a navigation based on pop() should be more appropriate. I tried with

```
onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).canPop()
                  ? Navigator.of(context)
                      .popUntil(ModalRoute.withName(PageA.routeName))
                  : Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(PageA.routeName);
            },
```

instead of `onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(PageA.routeName)`
But it doesn't work: when I tap on a drawer item a black screen appears, without any exception or warning, as if the navigator called a blank screen...

What am I doing wrong? Any idea how to fix?

This is my code:

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'page_c.dart';
import 'page_a.dart';
import 'page_b.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Navigation test',
      home: PageA(),
      routes: {
        PageA.routeName: (ctx) => PageA(),
        PageB.routeName: (ctx) => PageB(),
        PageC.routeName: (ctx) => PageC(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**my_drawer.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'page_b.dart';
import 'page_c.dart';
import 'page_a.dart';

class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 100,
          ),
          ListTile(
              title: Text('PAGE A'),
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(PageA.routeName)),
          ListTile(
              title: Text('PAGE B'),
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(PageB.routeName)),
          ListTile(
              title: Text('PAGE C'),
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(PageC.routeName)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**page_a.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'my_drawer.dart';

class PageA extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/route-a';

  @override
  _PageAState createState() => _PageAState();
}

class _PageAState extends State<PageA> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    print('PAGE A INIT STATE');
    super.initState();
  }

  // void didChangeDependencies() {
  //   print('PAGE A DID CHANGE DEPENDECIES');
  //   super.didChangeDependencies();
  // }

  // @override
  // void dispose() {
  //   print('PAGE A DISPOSE');
  //   super.dispose();
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('PAGE A')),
      drawer: MyDrawer(),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('A', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**page_b.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'my_drawer.dart';

class PageB extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/route-b';

  @override
  _PageBState createState() => _PageBState();
}

class _PageBState extends State<PageB> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    print('PAGE B INIT STATE');
    super.initState();
  }

  // void didChangeDependencies() {
  //   print('PAGE B DID CHANGE DEPENDECIES');
  //   super.didChangeDependencies();
  // }

  // @override
  // void dispose() {
  //   print('PAGE B DISPOSE');
  //   super.dispose();
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('PAGE B')),
      drawer: MyDrawer(),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('B', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**page_c.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'my_drawer.dart';

class PageC extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/route-c';

  @override
  _PageCState createState() => _PageCState();
}

class _PageCState extends State<PageC> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    print('PAGE C INIT STATE');
    super.initState();
  }

  // void didChangeDependencies() {
  //   print('PAGE C DID CHANGE DEPENDECIES');
  //   super.didChangeDependencies();
  // }

  // @override
  // void dispose() {
  //   print('PAGE C DISPOSE');
  //   super.dispose();
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('PAGE C')),
      drawer: MyDrawer(),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('C', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The pushNamed method of the navigator make a new instance of your page each time you call it and it is normal. If you want to keep your pages states, I think you should play with show/hide your pages inside a container.

Comment: Hello, did you find a answer to your problem ? i'm stuck with the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Flutter stack working flow]

As per image one flutter stack is working. Already A screen is added into stack. if you add B, it will be pushed on top of A only. Now, B and A are in stack. Now, A also in live state. B also in live state. B will be you're visible state screen. But at the background A also in running state. A will not be disposed.

Solution:

You should use `Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, B.id);`, By using popAndPushNamed method, you can remove the A from stack and B will be a active screen.